# Consume an api with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to consume an API that was created by using the annotation @RestRepositoryResources in Student Repository like this:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

So, I want to consume the API from another project like this:

```java
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        ListStudent response=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/student-service/students", ListStudent.class);
        System.out.println(response);
        return response.getStudents();
    }
}
```

Of course this is not working because the format of the response

```json
{
     "_embedded": {
     "students": []
    },
    "_links": {
    "self": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/students"
    },
    "profile": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8081/profile/students"
    }
    },
       "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 0,
        "totalPages": 0,
        "number": 0
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create POJOs that match the response, but a simpler option would be to change the `Content-Type`. Spring data rest uses `application/hal+json` by default; add a header to the request for `Content-Type: application/json`, and the response structure should be simpler to consume.

You may also set `spring.data.rest. default-media-type=application/json` in the `application.properties` to set default content type.

Comment: I added spring.data.rest.default-media-type=application/json and it is working perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `ListStudent` is but your class needs to match the JSON response, though it can omit anything you don't need. You need something like a `StudentResponse` class, which contains a `List<Student>`.